# Page Background-Color doesn't work (CSS)

Tags: css

I'm a real noob at CSS/HTML, so please forgive me.

I tried to change the background page color on the CSS file linked to my html file, and it doesn't work. Whereas when I just flat out change it between the style tags in my HTML file, it works. What gives?

Plain and simple:

Ex1.css

```
<head>
<style>
body {
   background-color: lightblue;
}
</style>
</head>
```

SamplePage.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Sample Page </title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="Ex1.css">
  </head>
  <body>

      Hello. This is a sample Page.

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your CSS file should not have HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is correct, and links to your CSS correctly (assuming `Ex1.css` is in the same folder as your HTML).

Your CSS is **almost** correct; the only problem is that you shouldn't include any HTML tags in your CSS document. `Ex1.css` should only contain the actual CSS declarations themselves (`body { }`).

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  Hello. This is a sample Page.
</body>
```

If in doubt, you can **validate** your CSS with **[W3's CSS Validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the contents of your `Ex1.css` file to this:

```
body {
   background-color: lightblue;
}
```

(no HTML code in CSS files!)

Answer (score 0):

your css file will just have. Plain and simple

```
body {
   background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your css file to this:

```
body {
   background-color: lightblue;
}
```